# Symfony 3 change label theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am using bootstrap 3 form theme.

```
{% use 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' with form_widget_simple as form_widget_simple_base, form_label as form_label_base %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block text_label %}
<span class="input-group-addon">{{ ???? }}</span>
{% endblock %}

{% block text_row %}
<div class="input-group">
    {{ block('text_label') }}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple_base') }}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h4>Product form</h4>
            {{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I can add to `text_label` {{ block('form_label_base') but it renders everyting in  tag. I would like to have simple label in text format without any html tags. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just put `label` var here:

```
{% block text_label %}
    <span class="input-group-addon">{{ label }}</span>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: When I dump form variables the label index is null.

Comment: So you have to set it up at the form builder. Or try to use `form.label`